# How to Automatically Align the Second Letter of an Acronym with a "Floating" Symbol on the Line Above

Tags: align, vertical-alignment, acronyms

Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\myred}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\noindent \textbf{(10)} * \\[-2pt]
\textbf{A.B.C.}

\vspace{15pt}

\noindent \textbf{(1020)} * \\[-2pt]
\textbf{J.Y.Z.}

\vspace{15pt}

\noindent \textbf{(573)} * \\[-2pt]
\textbf{X.Y.Z.}

\vskip 30pt

\noindent \myred{\textbf{(10)} * \\[-2pt]
\hspace*{12pt} \textbf{A.B.C.}}

\vspace{15pt}

\noindent \myred{\textbf{(1020)} * \\[-2pt]
\hspace*{34pt} \textbf{J.Y.Z.}}

\vspace{15pt}

\noindent \myred{\textbf{(573)} * \\[-2pt]
\hspace*{20pt} \textbf{X.Y.Z.}}
\end{document}
```

and the outout

[image]

The first three lines (in black) represent examples of a number within parentheses followed by a symbol, in this case given by an asterisk.

Although the asterisk in the MWE lies a fixed amount of space to the right of the enclosed number, this need not be the case in the actual document; i.e., it can *float*.

I must align the second initial in the acronym below with the above asterisk.

In red, I show what this is supposed to look like.

Alas, in order to do this, it is a matter of trial and error.

I would like to automate this process, if possible.

QUESTION: Is it possible, and if so, how may I automatically align the second letter in the acronym (with a dot after each letter) with an above symbol (always fixed, but in this case an asterisk) which will always occur to the right of the enclosed number but not necessarily a uniform distance from it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\def\zz#1{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}*\\\bfseries\zzz#1\relax\end{tabular}}
\def\zzz#1.#2.#3\relax{\llap{#1.}#2\rlap{.#3}}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
\noindent \textbf{(10)} \zz{A.B.C} 


\vspace{15pt}

\noindent \textbf{(1020)} \zz{J.Y.Z.}

\vspace{15pt}

\noindent \textbf{(573)} \zz{X.Y.Z.}

\vspace{15pt}

\noindent \textbf{(573)}  some other text \zz{X.Y.Z.}

\end{document}
```

this is setting the text in a table while hiding the width of the text apart from the second letter.

Comment: Thank you for this very fine answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `zref` package and its `savepos` module:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{xcolor} \newcommand{\myred}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\newcounter{alignmark}
\setcounter{alignmark}{0}

\AtBeginDocument{\zsaveposx{alignmargin}}%

\newcommand{\setalignmark}{%
    \stepcounter{alignmark}%
    \zsaveposx{alignmark\roman{alignmark}}%
}

\newcommand{\alignatmark}[3][\roman{alignmark}]{%
    \hspace*{\dimexpr\zposx{alignmark#1}sp-\zposx{alignmargin}sp\relax}\llap{#2}#3%
}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\noindent \textbf{(10)} \setalignmark * \\[-2pt]
\alignatmark{\textbf{A.}}{\textbf{B.C.}}

\vspace{15pt}

\noindent \textbf{(1020)} \setalignmark * \\[-2pt]
\alignatmark{\textbf{J.}}{\textbf{Y.Z.}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the `savepos` module, you can save the current position on the page and later get this position for example to shift something. Note that the position is calculated from the bottom left corner of the page. Therefore, in this example, we need to take into account the left margin. In case even end odd pages have different margins, this approach will need some adjustment.